# how to temporarily stop computer from sleeping in powershell?I

Tags: powershell

I have a long running powershell script and while it's running the computer goes to sleep.  Is there something I can do in powershell to suspend sleeping and then at the end of the script restore it to its previous state?

Comment: Try `powercfg /hibernate off` then `<rest of PS logic>` and finally `powercfg /hibernate on` and see if hibernation is the issue and if that resolves. You can read: https://ss64.com/nt/powercfg.html

Comment: That's a nice idea.  I don't have hibernate enabled, it's just sleeping. But I'm guessing I could use powercfg /SetActive GUID-high_power_scheme to turn off sleeping, then use powercfg /SetActive GUID-my_normal_scheme at the end.

Comment: Give it a shot and see if it works out for you. Tag me back with your final solution. I'm happy to add an answer if you wish or I'll be happy to upvote a self-answer if you add one. Either way, I'm happy to help you with the idea of giving some variant of `powercfg` commands that are applicable in your environment some thought for things to try to get you a solution.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Hopefully I'll remember to do it, next month when I do backups again.